# Cannot Get JSON for the JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm creating a JS object like this

```
var eleDetailsTop = new Array();

var j = 0;
var id = "ele"+j;
eleDetailsTop[id] = {id: id, size : "40%", sizeLabel : 12, type : "image", title : "Image"};
```

Now, I'm trying to convert this object to a JSON...

```
var fields = JSON.stringify(eleDetailsTop);
```

So, my problem is, this only gives an empty result.

Here is what I got when I debugged with FireBug

[image]

As you can see there is another object called `wrappedJSobject` inside this. If you checked inside it, you can see another `wrappedJSobject` as so on...

Why is this ? Why is this weird ?

Comment: What does that mean to have `eleDetailsTop[id]` when `id` is not a number?

Comment: If you log `eleDetailsTop.length`, you will see why.

Comment: You made `eleDetailsTop` an array, yet you populate it as if it's an object literal. It looks as if you want the array to be associative which is technically prohibited.

Comment: Thanks all ! I got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an array and assigning it alphanumeric property.
Try this:

```
var j = 0;
var id = "ele"+j;
eleDetailsTop[j] = {id: id, size : "40%", sizeLabel : 12, type : "image", title : "Image"};
```

EDIT: If you do want to use id as property - defined eleDetailsTop as object:

```
var eleDetailsTop = {};
```

Comment: Thanks, But I want the index using `id` Not with just `j`. The index should be a string like `eleDetailsTop['ele2']`.. Is that possible ?

Comment: @TharinduLucky then declare `var eleDetailsTop = {};`as an object.

Comment: Thanks! I din't know that :)  Anyway, I declare the object like you said, but the error still looks same.. :(

Comment: @TharinduLucky: Impossible.

Comment: @TharinduLucky works here: https://jsfiddle.net/r4zh0tgt/

Comment: Yeah, my bad. It's working :) Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
var eleDetailsTop = {};
```

Then you can assign properties like

```
eleDetailsTop[id] = {}
```

But if you really need the array... that won't work because there's no associative arrays in js technically (they're objects).

```
<script>

    var test = {};

    test['iam1234'] = {};

    console.log(test);

</script>
```

Comment: Define "work". It's absolutely possible to assign arbitrary properties to arrays, but you won't be able to include those properties when converted to JSON.

Comment: By "work", I was thinking he wouldn't be able to use Array methods like forEach, but You are absolutely correct, it does "work" like a normal array (aside from the JSON issue).